# Heroku Application Error (app runs fine locally)

Tags: python

Im trying all day to deploy this app (uses Flask and Plotly Dash). The deploying process works and the app runs locally without any problem but I always get an Application Error when I try to view the page and can't fix it

(mainly this one: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/").

Here is the Traceback and the errors:

> 2019-10-20T18:48:07.34022+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340229+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 210, in run 2019-10-20T18:48:07.34048+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.sleep() 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340483+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 360, in sleep 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340674+00:00 app[web.1]: ready
>   = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0) 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340678+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 245, in handle_chld 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340823+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.reap_workers() 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340827+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 528, in reap_workers 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341032+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341077+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: 
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.34108+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341081+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the
>   above exception, another exception occurred:
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341082+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341084+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341087+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in 
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341187+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341191+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
>   line 61, in run 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341332+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341338+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
>   line 223, in run 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341481+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   super(Application, self).run() 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341485+00:00
>   app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
>   line 72, in run 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341594+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   Arbiter(self).run() 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341596+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 232, in run 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341733+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.341737+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 345, in halt 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341907+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.stop() 2019-10-20T18:48:07.341912+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 393, in stop 2019-10-20T18:48:07.342087+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   time.sleep(0.1) 2019-10-20T18:48:07.342103+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 245, in handle_chld 2019-10-20T18:48:07.342235+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   self.reap_workers() 2019-10-20T18:48:07.34225+00:00 app[web.1]: File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
>   line 528, in reap_workers 2019-10-20T18:48:07.342455+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.342497+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: 
>   2019-10-20T18:48:07.398607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1 2019-10-20T18:48:07.340382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error
>   code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/"
>   host=dash-app-iwas.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=83c66979-c099-4f73-a736-ae8643738f23 fwd="178.4.195.229"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4943ms status=503 bytes=0
>   protocol=https 2019-10-20T18:48:07.43426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from up to crashed 2019-10-20T18:48:12.50511+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/favicon.ico" host=dash-app-iwas.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=ab745857-ec0c-4cec-b2a4-b28f16deeb28 fwd="178.4.195.229"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=5002ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2019-10-20T18:48:31+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
>   iwas.iwas@outlook.de 2019-10-20T18:49:18.55734+00:00 app[api]: Deploy
>   1c05a6c8 by user iwas.iwas@outlook.de 2019-10-20T18:49:18.55734+00:00
>   app[api]: Release v4 created by user iwas.iwas@outlook.de
>   2019-10-20T18:49:20.155422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-10-20T18:49:30.372836+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `gunicorn -b :8496 app:app`
>   2019-10-20T18:49:33.058813+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-20 18:49:33
>   +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0 2019-10-20T18:49:33.059689+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-20 18:49:33
>   +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8496 (4) 2019-10-20T18:49:33.059846+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-20 18:49:33
>   +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync 2019-10-20T18:49:33.068014+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-20 18:49:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker
>   with pid: 10

would be glad if someone could help me out I spend all day and can't fix it

The answer below fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set server instead of app in `Procfile`

In your `Procfile`  change

`web: gunicorn app:app` to

`web: gunicorn app:server`

For more information refer to the official dash guideline
https://dash.plot.ly/deployment